# Is a subring of a local ring still local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

If $B$ is a (unital) subring of a unital local ring $A$, is $B$ still a local ring?

If not, under which assumption is it true?

Comment: If $A$ has characteristic zero, then $\Bbb Z$ is a subring.

Comment: My question arises from the proof of Proposition 6.1 which appears here
http://sporadic.stanford.edu/modrep/ind6_1.html
when he says that any subring of the local ring $End_{R\otimes R^{op}}(R)$ is local. This seems not true in general to me (indeed you counterexample works) but I can't understand whether the proof works in this particular case or not

Comment: Every integral domain is a unital subring of a local ring (its field of fractions.) If you know any integral domains that aren't local (*pause*) then you have your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the author of that website means that a subring of that ring $A$ is local, or that each subring $B$ has all elements invertible or nilpotent. I can see that in this case each element of $B$ is either nilpotent, of has an **inverse in $A$** (but maybe not in $B$). But on that webpage, I think all the rings considered are finite-dimensional algebras over a field.

Comment: For a finite-dimensional algebra over a field I can say that any element which is not a zero-divisor is invertible. Thus, since the elements of $A$ are either nilpotent or invertible, so are the elements of $B$: in fact, if an element of $B$ is not nilpotent, then it has an inverse in $A$, but the inverse is actually in $B$ as this element can not be a zero-divisor (and $B$ is a unital subring, so inverse in $A$ = inverse in $B$). Moreover, this implies that $B$ is local. Is this correct? (sorry, I'm not an expert of this subject, so there might be some mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that for every element $c$ in $A$, we can find a unit $a \in A$ and an element $b \in B$ such that $ab = c$. Then it is easy to see that the map
$$
I \mapsto I \cap B,
$$
sending ideals of $A$ to ideals of $B$, is an order isomorphism w.r.t. inclusion.